# Make Twitter Bootstrap navbar go to top of page on collapse

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I am wondering what would be best practice in this situation. I have a navbar in a twitter bootstrap page and there is content above the page when viewed on a desktop. The navbar collapses when the screen width is low enough, but after the collapse the navbar is in the same position but I want it to be at the top of the page after collapse. What would be the best way to do this?

Here is my demo: http://www.bootply.com/61283

Comment: You should add code & demo

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the standard Bootstrap nav-collapse for the navbar, you could use the 'visible-desktop' for the desktop-only content:

```
<div class="container visible-desktop">Desktop only content above nav..</div>
```

On smaller screens this will not show, and as a result the navbar will display at the top.

[**Demo 1**](http://www.bootply.com/61214)

EDIT (alternative):

An alternative method would be to use @media queries and change the CSS to position elements on the smaller screens..

```
@media (max-width: 767px) { 
    .navbar{
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
    }
    #topContent{
        margin-top:45px;
    }
}
```

[**Demo 2**](http://www.bootply.com/61218)

Comment: Thanks, but I want the content still visable on collapse but I want it below the navbar rather than above.

Comment: See demo 2.. you may need to adjust the CSS

Comment: On the demo 2 the text disappears when the navbar collapses.

Comment: Only problem now is that the content doesn't move down when the menu is opened